# Using both Django template and React

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

Hi guys I’m trying to bulid a website which django works as an rest-api and react works as a front side. I manage to do the whole thing just fine and about to deploy it using aws. But there is one thing I couldn’t really get. Inside my django project I have an app that uses only django template to render things to front. And other apps are working only as apis to get and post things via react. Is it possible to deploy this kind of structure without any special options? I searched internet for a while but I couldn’t really find an example that fits my situation. Thanks!

Comment: I hope I get your question right. I think there will be no problem since pages and routes defined by specific path then the request will redirect to the template or to the api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to deploy it without extra options: you can have one Django template view to host the React app entry point, and the rest would be Rest API views that are accessed by React.